# Circuitikz opamp scale

Tags: circuitikz

I would like to ask you, how it is possible to scale size of opamp in my Circuitikz drawing. I try

```
  \ctikzset{tripoles/op amp/scale=0.5}
```

but unfortunately it does not work. I found only few examples in chapter 7.2 of the [circuitikzmanual](http://mirror.unicorncloud.org/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf).

MNWE

```
  \begin{circuitikz}[scale=1, every node/.style={scale=1}]
    \ctikzset{resistor=european}
    \draw (0,0) node[op amp] (opamp) {};
    \node [left=0.1cm of opamp.-]       (p1) {};
    \node [left=0.1cm of opamp.+]       (p2) {};
    \node [above=0.8cm of p1]           (A)  {};
    \node [left=1.5cm of A]             (p3) {};
    \node [right=2.7cm of A, coordinate](C)  {};
    \node [right=0.8cm of C]            (p6) {};
    \node [below=0.8cm of p2]           (B)  {};
    \node [left=1.5cm of B]             (p4) {};
    \node [right=2.5cm of B]        (ground) {};
    \node [right=0.1cm of opamp.out, coordinate] (vo) {};
    %%% Draw connections
    \draw (p3) node[left] {$u_1$} to[R=$R_1$,o-] (A)  to[R=$R_2$,*-] (C); 
    \draw (opamp.-)   to[short] (p1) to[short] (A);
    \draw (opamp.out) to[short] (vo);
    \draw (vo) to[short,-*] (vo |- C); 
    \draw (p4) node[left] {$u_2$} to[R=$R_3$,o-] (B)  to[R=$R_4$,*-] (ground) node [sground] {};  
    \draw (opamp.+) to[short] (p2) to[short] (B); 
    \draw (C) to[short,-o] (p6) node[right] {$u_{0}$};
    \node[above] at (A) {A}; % text 
    \node[below] at (B) {B}; % text 
  \end{circuitikz}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, looking answers to this old question ... their results are to my opinion a bit strange (not useful) regardless that correctly show possibilities how to scale amplifiers.

Also the answers as well question gives very unusual (to my opinion wrong) result. To draw this circuit -- a bit scaled down -- on the usual way, I suggest to scale beside amplifier shape also scale the `amp symbol` and resistor size (that sizes of all elements would be balanced)  accordingly, and change a way of drawing of circuit too:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[european]
\ctikzset{resistors/scale=.6,
          amplifiers/scale=0.8,
          amp symbol font={\footnotesize}
          }
\draw   (0,0)   node[op amp] (oa)    {}
        (oa.-)  to [short, -*]   ++ ( 0,1)      coordinate[label=above:A] (A) 
                to [R, a=$R_1$,*-o] ++ (-2,0)   node[left]  {$u_1$}
        (A)     to [R=$R_2$]        ++ ( 2,0)   coordinate  (C) 
                to [short, *-o]     ++ ( 1,0)   node[right] {$u_o$}
        (C)     |-  (oa.out)
        (oa.+)  to [short, -*]      ++ (0,-1)   coordinate[label=below:B] (B)
                to [R, a=$R_3$,*-o] ++ (-2,0)   node[left]  {$u_1$}
        (B)     to [R=$R_5$]        ++ ( 2,0)   node [sground] {}  
                ;
    \end{circuitikz} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not sure, if above MWE and obtained result is what OP looking for. At least suggested MWE in comparison to OP MWE is much shorter and simpler.

Answer (score 4):

Use the scale at the node generation.

```
\node[op amp, scale = xx]
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  It can be good to also add a complete small document showing the use in context and with an image of the output.

Answer (score 0):

Op amps belong to the amplifiers class (see [manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/circuitikzmanual.pdf)), so your example should work if you substitute `\ctikzset{tripoles/op amp/scale=0.5}` with `\ctikzset{amplifiers/scale=0.5}`

```
  \begin{circuitikz}[scale=1, every node/.style={scale=1}]
    \ctikzset{resistor=european, amplifiers/scale=.7}
    \draw (0,0) node[op amp] (opamp) {};
    \node [left=0.1cm of opamp.-]       (p1) {};
    \node [left=0.1cm of opamp.+]       (p2) {};
    \node [above=0.8cm of p1]           (A)  {};
    \node [left=1.5cm of A]             (p3) {};
    \node [right=2.7cm of A, coordinate](C)  {};
    \node [right=0.8cm of C]            (p6) {};
    \node [below=0.8cm of p2]           (B)  {};
    \node [left=1.5cm of B]             (p4) {};
    \node [right=2.5cm of B]        (ground) {};
    \node [right=0.1cm of opamp.out, coordinate] (vo) {};
    %%% Draw connections
    \draw (p3) node[left] {$u_1$} to[R=$R_1$,o-] (A)  to[R=$R_2$,*-] (C); 
    \draw (opamp.-)   to[short] (p1) to[short] (A);
    \draw (opamp.out) to[short] (vo);
    \draw (vo) to[short,-*] (vo |- C); 
    \draw (p4) node[left] {$u_2$} to[R=$R_3$,o-] (B)  to[R=$R_4$,*-] (ground) node [sground] {};  
    \draw (opamp.+) to[short] (p2) to[short] (B); 
    \draw (C) to[short,-o] (p6) node[right] {$u_{0}$};
    \node[above] at (A) {A}; % text 
    \node[below] at (B) {B}; % text 
  \end{circuitikz}
```

[image]

Comment: Your example needs the positioning library, else the “of” operators aren’t known.  Please include it in the MWE